# Make button enabled for only one user on webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm developing a website that is suppoused to control some devices that rotate when pushing one button. However, I only want one user at a time to be able to push the button.

That is, when a user enters the page, check if it is the "first" or only user that is there. In case he is, he can use the button freely. In case he isn't, the button appears as disabled.

What would be the best way to implement this? I'm using a classic design of html+js+php.

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far? How do you store user sessions? Do you have a centralized storage system where you can compare the current user's session to a state in the backend?

Comment: `What would be the best way to implement this?` The best way is the way that works and go from there. You should do that research first, then try something out that suits you best. If you have any issues with your code post it here in a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - Also have a look at what Questions [**Are On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and which ones [**Are not On-Topic**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a design question, and still, you should have already tried something and post that something before asking here.

You should use a lock system:

create an endpoint with php, to call with Ajax that checks over a variable globally shared (better if on db) that acts like a semaphore, the first who arrive make it red and 'acquire the lock'.

If the lock is acquired, the client can do the action,

If the lock is not acquired, someone else took it already.

Do not forget to release the lock after the action.

You can use the same call to acquire the lock, do the action and release the lock. If the lock is not acquired the call return an error message and the user will know which is the issue.

P.S.

If you was thinking about a real time system, you may consider using websockets or just the system above with different calls for acquire the lock and do the action (and poll for the lock status).

Comment: Thank you, I actually thought about using text files or databases but I felt terribly inefficient, that's why I came to ask. I also searched for a bit before asking. Sorry about that.

I will work with the php semaphore via AJAX :)

Answer (score 0):

To track a user on a website is not that difficult, but check if and when he/she leaves is the challenge.

If this is not time crucial you can do this with timeouts.

First, you need to be able to track the current user on your site (maybe with sqlite, textfile, mysql/mariadb) (maybe identified by IP) wich is updated a user loads the page.
After a timeout the tracking storage can be updated and the next or new one can hold the button.

If you need this realtime, you need a bit more to do. In this case I would use Websockets or NodeJS to keep connections to your page wich in fact you can use to keep track on active users and wich one should be able to keep the button.
Just keep it like a realtime online chat without texting. There you need to keep track of online users as well.

(Websockets or NodeJS are here only a example, there are alot technique to archive realtime "collaboration".)